# Log levels are not applied in sub packages

Tags: spring-boot, error-logging

- Question: Info logs are not output in the subpackage (C2).
  Error log output from C2.
- Project structure
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G2YB.png)
- application-local.yml

```
 logging:
  config: classpath:log4j2-prd.xml
  level:
    root: error
    com.A.B: error
    com.A.B.C2: info 
    jdbc.sqlonly: error
    jdbc.resultsettable: error
    org.springframework.data.redis: error
    org.springframework.web: error
    com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource: error
    com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig: error
    com.zaxxer.hikari: error
```

- C2 Source code
  `: import org.slf4j.Logger; : private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(####); : logger.info("Info log Test");`

how to print info log

Comment: Can you try with capitals ? like INFO, ERROR, DEBUG , let me know if it works

Comment: I changed it to upper case, but the same symptom (no log output).

Comment: Where is this info log statement? within a method or constructor? can you help with it?